# Language detection in R with the textcat package : how to restrict to a few languages?

Tags: r, nlp

I need to detect the language of many short texts, using R.
I am using the textcat package, which find which among many (say 30) European
languages is the one of each text. However, I know my texts are either French or English (or, more generally, a small subset of the langages handled by textcat).

How could add this knowledge when calling textcat functions ?

Thanks,

Comment: Consider adding example text that you wish to classify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *might* work.  Presumably you wish to restrict the language choices to English or French to reduce the misclassification rate.  Without example text for which the desired result is known I cannot test the approach below.  However, it does seem to restrict the language choices to English and French.

```
my.profiles <- TC_byte_profiles[names(TC_byte_profiles) %in% c("english", "french")]
my.profiles

my.text <- c("This is an English sentence.",
             "Das ist ein deutscher Satz.",
            "Il s'agit d'une phrase française.",
            "Esta es una frase en espa~nol.")

textcat(my.text, p = my.profiles)

# [1] "english" "english" "french"  "french"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve high classification accuracy with the builtin ECIMCI_profiles.

Call

```
textcat(my.text, p = ECIMCI_profiles)
```

and optionally combine this with the `%in%` line-of-code from Mark Miller's answer.

The  `ECIMCI_profiles` database of package `textcat` uses a larger maximal n-gram size of 1000 (unlike 400 as the `TC_byte_profiles` or `TC_char_profiles` dbs).